# Getting username and password exposed in POST parameters when created a new user

Tags: php, encryption, yii, authentication

I need to hash and store a password from user input in login form in Yii.
If I get them thru POST parameters like this:

```
$model->username=$_POST['User']['username'];
$model->password=crypt($_POST['User']['username']);// salt might be added
if($model->save())
  $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
```

this way I expose the uncrypted password in POST request. 
Other way is to them directly from login form like this:

```
public function actionCreate2()
{
    $model=new User;
    $model->username = $form->username;
    $model->password = crypt($form->password);
    if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

but this **does not work** in my case with authenticating a saved user. 
The auth function:

```
public function authenticate()
{
    $users = User::model()->findByAttributes(array('username'=>$this->username));

    if($users == null)
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
    elseif ($users->password !== crypt($this->password, $users->password))
    //elseif($users->password !== $this->password)
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
    else
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
    return !$this->errorCode;
}
```

How to do it in a proper way?

The more troubles appeared as i followed suggest of Samuel - the validating alarm message even before i enter anything, along with hashed password in input field.(see the picture):
[image: more trouble]

When I still enter my username and my password instead of 'proposed' and press 'Create' the form is being sent with not crypted values (from POST request sniffing):

```
Form Data   view source   view URL   encoded
YII_CSRF_TOKEN:9758c50299b9d4b96b6ac6a2e5f0c939eae46abe
User[username]:igor23
User[password]:igor23
yt0:Create
```

but nothing is actually stored in db, nor crypted not uncrypted...

Comment: What error you got? Did you try to dump the crypt of password of saved user with crypt of passowrod from login form yet?

Comment: In `authenticate` you are passing the hashed password as the salt, while when saving there is no salt passed, hence the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your create method to:

```
/**
 * Creates a new model.
 * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
 */
public function actionCreate() {
    $model = new User;

    if (isset($_POST['User'])) {
        $model->attributes = $_POST['User'];
        $model->password = crypt($model->password, 'mysalt123');

        if ($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->primaryKey));
    }

    // Reset password field
    $model->password = "";

    $this->render('create', array(
        'model' => $model,
    ));
}
```

Change that elseif from this:

```
elseif ($users->password !== crypt($this->password, $users->password))
```

To this:

```
elseif (strcmp(crypt($this->password, 'mysalt123'), $users->password))
```

Comment: i've followed your suggest, no avail. rather now i've from the very beginning the alarm about field *Name* to fill and the hashed password value in the form input area. See picture at the end of question.

Comment: this is for authenticate, true. But it seems the controller action gets an empty value from the form, crypt it and put in the password input form field for my trouble. 
Also i do not want validation messages from the beginning, before any input.

Comment: thank you, Samuel, now it works smooth (no junk in form input, data are saved in db), yet the encryption fails to validate a fresh created user.

Comment: As i checked in sniffer, the uncrypted password is exposed as a POST parameter...

Comment: Samuel, i followed your instruction, even dumped these data: **$users->password** = $1$DqHgDGby$h0Zg0E.YiQgY938WrOwov.
**crypt($this->password)** = $1$SqcHA3Mc$p8GoSWvAjbqTiqMH.DcGp. They do not match. What's problem?

Comment: Thank you, Samuel, very much!!!. I'll give you a bonus, the gospel track (since i'm a christian): http://churchintlt.ru/Pages/MysteryENG.html